# Error: uiCodemirror3 can only be applied to a textarea element

Tags: angularjs, codemirror, ui-codemirror

According to the doc of [ui-codemirror](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror):

> The ui-codemirror directive plays nicely with ng-model.
>
> The ng-model will be watched for to set the CodeMirror document value (by setValue).
>
> The ui-codemirror directive stores and expects the model value to be a standard javascript String.

However, my following code ([JSBin](https://jsbin.com/mefazafuki/1/edit?html,output)) returns an error `Error: uiCodemirror3 can only be applied to a textarea element` in the console.

```
<html ng-app="flapperNews">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
  <script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
  <script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
  <script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui']);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.x = "<html><body>abc</body></html>";
    }])
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ui-codemirror ng-model="x"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to correctly use ui-codemirror **directive**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following libraries

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-codemirror/0.3.0/ui-codemirror.js"></script>
```

and remove the following

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js"></script>
```

angular-ui.js has old codemirror directives

and inject

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.codemirror']);
```

Example [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/muguzelapu/edit?html,output)

Comment: Your codepen keeps reloading/refreshing for me, but the idea is correct. Here is the [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/zamiwetice/1/edit?html,output) for the record... Thank you...

Comment: That's the same code, I updated the link, might be some issue with codepen.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `div` with `textarea` like following code ( [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/sepahupaso/edit?html,console,output) )

```
<textarea ui-codemirror ng-model="x"></textarea>
```

You could find the error message in
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js
but https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror/blob/master/src/ui-codemirror.js doesn't have that.

So you could wait for `angular-ui` to update it or use `ui-codemirror` separately to have last changes.

Comment: I know that way would work (which has some limitations), what i want is to make `<div ui-codemirror ...` or `<ui-codemirror>...` work, as their doc describes...