# Flick from a textarea to a ui-codemirror frame

Tags: css, angularjs, textarea, codemirror, ui-codemirror

I want to make an editor of files. By the following code ([JSBin](https://jsbin.com/jihuvejoyo/1/edit?html,output)), we list all the file names on the left hand, and their body on the right hand. I use `ui-codemirror` to style the body of the files.

However, when we click on the file names and switch from one to another, **from time to time, we could see the quick flick from a textarea to a codemirror frame, which is not a good experience for an editor.**

Does anyone have a solution to avoid the flick? Addtionally, is it a good direction to make an editor by `angularJS` and `ui-codemirror`?

```
<html ng-app="flapperNews">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
  <script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
  <script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
  <script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.11.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui', 'ui.router']);

    app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('file', {
          template: '<textarea ui-codemirror="editorOptionsHTML" ng-model="file.body"></textarea>',
          controller: 'FileCtrl',
          params: { name: null }
        })
    }]);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
      $scope.files = [
        { name: "index.html", body: "<html><body>index.html</body></html>" },
        { name: "index.js", body: "the body of index.js" },
        { name: "test.html", body: "the body of test.html" }];
    }]);

    app.controller('FileCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
      $scope.file = $scope.files.find(function (file) { return file.name === $stateParams.name });
      $scope.editorOptionsHTML = { mode: 'text/html', lineNumbers: true, matchBrackets: true };
    }]);
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-3">
      <div ng-repeat="file in files track by $index">
        <a ui-sref="file({name: file.name})">{{file.name}}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-xl-9 col-lg-9">
      <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you click on the link, it is creating new editor, which is an expense operation.

```
The best approach is to create one editor and load the content on every click.
```

so I removed the ui-router linking (ui-sref) and related controllers

```
<script>
 var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui', 'ui.router']);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
   $scope.files = [
    { name: "index.html", body: "<html><body>index.html</body></html>" },
    { name: "index.js", body: "the body of index.js" },
    { name: "test.html", body: "the body of test.html" }];

   $scope.editorOptionsHTML = { mode: 'text/html', lineNumbers: true, matchBrackets: true };


  // for every click event it will load the content
   $scope.go=function(file){
     $scope.file=file;
   }
  }]);
```

and the body

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-3">
      <div ng-repeat="file in files track by $index">
        <a ng-click="go(file)">{{file.name}}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-xl-9 col-lg-9">
      <textarea ui-codemirror="editorOptionsHTML" ng-model="file.body"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Example : [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/jafotoyopo/edit?html,output)

Comment: I don't know why your codepen does not work... Here is my [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/tiducocevu/1/edit?html,output) with the same idea...

Answer (score 0):

you could avoid the flick by adding `hide` class to `textarea` like the following code ( [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/defubikuku/edit?html,output) )

```
template: '<textarea class="hide" ui-codemirror="editorOptionsHTML" ng-model="file.body"></textarea>',
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... It is better now, we could not see flick **from textarea to ui-codemirror** anymore. However, we could still see flick **from time to time** when we switch files (even though between two files with the same content), I tested it in Chrome and Safari. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: I realised that changing external links like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42316338/702977) solved the problem...